# Prove that $D(A,B)=0$ if and only if some sequence of points in $A$ converges to a point in $B$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $D(A,B)=0$ if and only if some sequence of points in $A$ converges to a point in $B$

This is what I got.

Let $a∈A, b∈B$. Suppose$ a_n∈A$. We now will prove this statement in 2 parts.

Part 1: if $D(A,B)=0$ then some sequence of points in $A$ converges to a point in $B$

Assume that $D(A,B)=0$, we will show that some sequence $a_n$ of points in $ A$ converges to a point in $B$

Since $D(A,B)=0$, we obtain

$D(a,B)=D(A,b)=D(a,b)=0$

This implies that

$D(a_n,b)=0$

Let $ε>0$, then 
$D(a_n b)<ε$

This implies that $a_n∈N_ε (b)$. In other word, there is some sequence of points in A converges to a point b in B.

Part 2: if there is some sequence of points in $A$ converges to a point in B, then $D(A,B)=0$

Assume that some sequence $a_n$ of points in A converges to a point in B. We will show that $D(A,B)=0$.
Since sequence $a_n$ of points in A converges to a point in B, there is a point b∈B such that for all $ε>0$,
$a_n∈N_ε (b)$

This means
$D(a_n,b)<ε$

Now I'm stuck $D(a_n,b)<ε$ can guarantee that $D(a_n,b)=0$

Comment: $D(a_n,b)$ will never necessarily be zero. 

But since there is an $a \in A$ in every neighborhood of a specific $b \in B$, then $D(A,b):=\inf\{{d(a_n,b), b \in B}\}$ must be $0$

Comment: Is $D$ the notation of a metric here? What if $A=(-1,0)$ and $B=(0,1)$ are intervals in $\mathbb R$ and $D(a,b):=|a-b|$? Then $D(A,B)=0$ since for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $|a-b|<\varepsilon$. However, there is no point in $B=(0,1)$ that serves as limitpoint for a sequence in $A$. There must be extra conditions to make this true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first part is actually not right.

If you had a sequence of points from $A$ which converged to a point in $B$, but were never elements of B, $D(a,B)=0$, but for any two points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $D(a,b)>0$.

A similar reasoning applies to your second part. You will never guarantee that $D(a_n,b)=0$ necessarily. Mostly you can say $D(\{a_n\},b)=0$.